# NavController crashes when forcing screen rotation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

When navigating from the first screen to the second screen using the NavController in Jetpack Compose the app crashes. The first screen is locked to landscape then the second screen should be locked to portrait. I am locking the screen orientation using:

```
    @Composable
    fun SimpleCameraPreview(navController: NavController) {

        val navController= remember{navController}

        val activity = (LocalContext.current as Activity)
        activity.requestedOrientation=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE

        navController.navigate("NFCReader"). //CRASHES HERE
  }
```

and same for:

```
 @Composable
 fun NFCReader() {

     val activity = (LocalContext.current as Activity)
     activity.requestedOrientation=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
 }
```

Immediately after navigate() is called the app crashes with error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event down from INITIALIZED 
in component androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry@50241114"
```

However if I remove the orientation change on the NFCReader screen the app does not crash ,like so:

```
 @Composable
 fun NFCReader() {

    //no orientation enforcement
 }
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this whilst locking screen orientations? Thanks

Comment: You must not ever call `navigate` as part of composition (since composition can happen many, many times e.g. when an animation is happening). Nor should you be doing any state changes like changing the requested orientation in composition either. Have you read the page on [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call this framework functions in composable code. They are probably called more than once. You can use a SideEffect(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) for these kinds of functionality.